# OSGI Bundle, maven-bundle-plugin, signed JARS

Tags: java, maven, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm using the maven-bundle-plugin to build an OSGIed version of a bunch of Jar files, some of which are signed. This seems to create a problem later on in my build, with the following error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

I think this is due to the generated .RSA and .SF files which get embedded. How do I specify the exclusion of these files in my configuration? The following is my current configuration.

```
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>!javax.servlet.*,!org.apache.commons.logging,*</Export-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Directory>OSGI-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    <Import-Package>!javax.jms,!javax.resource.*, !junit.*,!net.sf.ehcache,!net.spy.memcached,!org.apache.avalon.framework.logger,*</Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
```